# Packet analyzer with timeout and packets summary to be used with bash script

Tags: bash, packet-sniffers

I am searching for a packet analyzer tool which can write both parsed packet infos and packets' summary (like *tcpdump*) but also has a timeout such that if the specific time has elapsed, it will stop sniffing.

**tcpdump** doesn't have this ***timeout*** feature. Right now, I am using **sleep** to delay and then sending **kill -INT** to capture the summary along with the info.

**wireshark** invokes a GUI and does not give parsed packet info nor packets' summary when written to a file. We have to use tcpdump to get parsed packet info. But there's no way to get packets' summary.

Other packet sniffers like *dsniff, ettercap, ngrep, xplico* has similar issues.

Hence, please help me find a packet sniffer/analyzer which can take 'timeout' as a parameter and produces parsed packet info along with packets' summary (number of packets processed, ... like *tcpdump*).

Answer (score 2):

You can tell tcpdump to stop after a given packet count with the `-c` flag. Given that you first get an idea of how much data flows through you can decide on an amount of data and collect that number of packets. This way you get a fixed amount of data, but whether it takes 5 or 6 or 7 minutes is out of your control. There is also a `-G` flag that will write your captured data to (new) files every N seconds. 
...or you can use the `timeout` command, i.e.:

```
timeout 60 tcpdump -i eth0 port 80 -w output.cap
```

This will run tcpdump for 60 seconds, then exit. It does what you already do in a less clumsy fashion :--)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the timeout command. And yeah I knew about 'c' and 'G' flags but we didn't want what those flags do. And -w doesn't give the parsed packet info but just the raw info. So, I am redirecting stdout and stderr to get the parsed packet info and packet summary.

Comment: Yeah it's just an example command ;) tcpdump can parse the packet info from a dump later too... The timeout command is a pretty handy tool, but it's not so widely known for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

```
sudo tcpdump -Z root -w ~/dump.bin -n -i eth0 -G 300 -W 1
```

```
G - Timeout Seconds (After timeout period the comman gets killed automatically)

Z - drops the root and runs as user privilege

W - Number files to be saved (as a splitted file)
```

Comment: The Problem with this aproach is, that "-G" does not timeout if there are no packets received. So the solution above with timeout is the better.